# Heroku dyno/processes

Tags: heroku

Reading the Heroku documentation I don't understand the match between processes and dynos, is there one process per dyno ? Or can there be multiple processes per dyno ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One dyno is one container. You can imagine it as one server.

Heroku allows you to monitor a single process per dyno, restarting the dyno on another instance if that process crashes.
But you can boot multiple ones if you wish. If they crash, they won't automatically be restarted though.

One way to do that would be to create a `start-process` file, and give it the `+x` chmod flag so it can be executed.

Then, within that file, you'd have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
start-first-process &
start-second-process
```

This will start the first process (don't forget the `&` at the end, so it's started in the background) and then start the second process, and consider it as the main one (if it stops, your dyno restarts).

Your Procfile will then look like this:

```
worker: start-process
```

The dyno will be named `worker`, and you can scale it up with:

> heroku ps:scale worker=1

Comment: Thank you! How would you do that using the Procfile?

Comment: Thank you, that's an interesting way to test multiple processes without the cost !